# Backbone.LocalStorage is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I am using backbone localstorage plugin however, it is giving me following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Backbone.LocalStorage is not a function

I am using it in following way in my collection

```
var TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TodoModel,
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('todos-backbone')
});
```

How can I solve this problem?

**UPDATE**

I import them in index.html

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/backbone/node_modules/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/backbone-localstorage/backbone-localStorage.js"></script>
<script src="js/models/todo.js"></script>
<script src="js/collections/todos.js"></script>
<script src="js/views/todos.js"></script>
<script src="js/views/app.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="js/routers/router.js"></script> -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please show us the HTML where you import the backbone modules

Comment: Is there any file permission issues ?

Comment: @ErrHunter what do you mean by file permission?

Comment: your `backbone-localStorage.js` is having read permission for everyone ? I used to get stuck with permissions.

Comment: I dont really think. I have these permissions on `backbone-localstorage.js`  `-rw-r--r--`

Comment: Seems odd that libs have hyphens in them instead of periods. Have you checked paths are correct?

Comment: yes they are correct. They have hyphens in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage and https://github.com/robmoorman/backbone-localstorage. `Backbone.LocalStorage` is a function only in the former while the one you have included is used like this:

```
var TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TodoModel,
    localStorage: true
});
```